# Formula that gives linear increase in output when input doubles.

Tags: exponential-function

I am looking for a formula that will take x and output y like so:

```
1        100
2        400
4        700
8        1000
16       1300
...
```

Essentially, for every doubling of the input, output increases by a fixed value. In this case 300, offset by 100 but that's not important.
What's important is that for every doubling of the input value, i want a linear increase in output.

But there's another problem. I cannot make use of power, square roots or logarithms etc. And i can't use decimal numbers. I.E 1.512457256.... I can however use integers up to 2^31 so i can represent 1.51 as 151 / 100 and work with that in my problem.
The operations i have available to me are the simple ones as well as bitwise operations:

`+, -, /, * and %
&, |, ^, << and >>`

Or in other words, addition, subtraction, division, multiplication and modulus...
As well as bitwise AND, OR, XOR, Left Shift and Right Shift.

I can also use these simple functions: `max(), min() and abs()`

Can this be accomplished and if so, how?

Please try and keep it simple. I have practically no skills in maths. I don't work well with "advanced" notation.

EDIT:

Note that decimal accuracy is not important. Hence, as Jaume Oliver Lafont points out below, i can check which bit is set to one in the input value and work with that as the log2(x) if need be.

But at that point, which i neglected to mention, i can use ranges and hardcode the log values as well. But i would rather avoid it if possible.
However, without log2(x) i now do realize how impossible this would be. Unless there's some very intelligent approximation of log2(x) one can use.

Comment: You need a logarithmic function. Using only simple and bitwise operations, that will get complicated. Are you allowed to write a program, use loops, if statements, etc? Are you able to get the number of bits/digits of a binary number?

Comment: @Bemte I can do limited conditional branching only. Either way, i cannot implement a logarithmic function in my environment no. And i figured as much when it struck me that i could do log2(x) to turn the exponential nature of this into a linear one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is

$$f(x)=100+300\log_2(x)$$

At the points you give, $\log_2(x)$ is the position of the non-zero bit.

Can you write a log2(x) function?

Here are some ways to build such a function.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376288/fast-computing-of-log2-for-64-bit-integers

Comment: I specifically stated i can only use a limited set of functions and operations. But i do realize that i kinda have to use log2(x) to solve this unless there's some very crude approximation i can use in it's place?

Comment: After your edit, no i cannot write a log2(x) function. But you did mention the position of the non-zero bit which does make a lot of sense. I can use this newfound "eureka" moment for sure!

Comment: Maybe a crude approximation you may use if accuracy is not very important can be piecewise linear approximation. Classify your number between successive powers of two and then interpolate linearly between them.

Comment: Numbers for a segment look like this, to the left the approximation and to the right the desired value:

$$break> for (k=0,8,print(1000+k*300/8.," ",100+300*log(k+8)/log(2)))$$
$$1000, 1000.000000$$
$$1037.500000, 1050.977500$$
$$1075.000000, 1096.578428$$
$$1112.500000, 1137.829486$$
$$1150.000000, 1175.488750$$
$$1187.500000, 1210.131915$$
$$1225.000000, 1242.206477$$
$$1262.500000, 1272.067179$$
$$1300.000000, 1300.000000$$

Comment: I like how impossible it is to comment properly. Anyways, i will basically do `log = (value & 0x8) > 0 ? 3 : ...` to get the logarithm of the value and yes, i will do linear interpolation after that. Thanks!